# Is their Correct to call init() in onkeyEvent() in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I call init() in onkeyEvent(). But Eclipse Building Workspace slow to call init(). I removed then work fine. Is It correct I call init() in onkeyevent()?

Answer (score 0):

*init()* function is used to initialize corresponding xml components and some scripted controls, for example setting observer fields. It is not recommended to call *init()* manually. **If you have some functionality in *init()* that you want to invoke again, then keep that functionality in seperate function. Call that function once in *init()* and again whenever you want.**